# ¿Cómo generar a partir de un diccionario una matriz?

Tags: python, matrices, diccionarios

Digamos que tengo un diccionario de este estilo:

`EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados = {(0, 3): -1, (0, 2): 1, (0, 1): 1, (0, 4): 1, (1, 2): -1, (1, 3): 1}`

En donde cada clave es un vector bidimensional o un par ordenado, como quieran verlo. Y su valor es 1 o -1 si está en EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados y 0 si no está en EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados.

Para formar una matriz simétrica, cada clave (a, b) del diccionario es la posición en la matriz (a+1, b+1), de este modo, (0, 3) en el diccionario, sería la posición en la matriz (1, 4), y su valor sería -1, tanto en la entrada (1, 4) como en la entrada (4, 1), pues es una matriz simétrica. Si su valor es 1 como la clave (0, 2), entonces en la entrada de la matriz (1, 3) y (3, 1) iría un 1, y si no aparece una clave, como por ejemplo (0, 0) en EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados, entonces en la matriz sería la posición (1, 1) y valdría 0.

Con el ejemplo EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados quiero formar una MatrizSignada, dada con las reglas del párrafo anterior, y formar una matriz parecida a esto:

```
MatrizSignada = ([ 0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
                 [ 1.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.],
                 [ 1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                 [-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Pero eso me gustaría hacerlo para un diccionario cualquiera con esa forma, clave: (a, b) tupla bidimensional | valor: (1, -1 si aparece en el diccionario y 0 si no aparece) valor entero.

Esto no es una tarea o proyecto, simplemente no se cómo pasar ese tipo de diccionario a una matriz cuadrada simétrica. Evidentemente lo quiero para algo mucho más grande como parte de una investigación, pero esa es la parte que no sé cómo hacer.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Interesante problema, pero si no aportas código, no hay como empezar a darte una respuesta.

Comment: Ya puse el ejemplo, a partir del diccionario que nombré _EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados_ quiero generar la matriz _MatrizSignada_ con las reglas del cuarto párrafo, es el ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable, porque con dichas reglas puedes formar la matriz de manera matemática, aunque no sé cómo hacerlo en Python. No sé como tomar en el diccionario la clave (a, b), para la posición (a+1, b+1) en una matriz cuadrada simétrica (y por ende, (b+1, a+1)), y a esa pocisión en la matriz darle el valor del diccionario 1 o -1 (o 0 si no está en el diccionario).

Comment: Tengo un código, pero ese código genera de manera aleatoria el diccionario de _EnlacesPonderadosOrdenados_ y eso es lo que yo no quiero, generarlos de manera aleatoria, porque tengo las relaciones bien definidas entre individuos de manera experimental. Y a partir de ese diccionario, quiero generar la _MatrizSignada_, lo que quiero es lo contrario a ese código que tengo. Dado dicho diccionario formar la matriz. Y el código que tengo lo hace de manera aleatoria.

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya pude resolver mi problema.